# Linq To SQL, why the huge performance difference between two similar queries that are returning the same number of records

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

I have two queries, the first returns all "Open" records where the reply-by-date has not passed and the second returns all "Open Unviewed" records where the reply-by-date has not passed and the record has not been viewed by the user (no entry in table RfqVieweds). In this scenario the user has not viewed any of the 1000 records so all 1000 are returned. The second to last line in each query (right before "select new RfqDto()") is where the difference is between the two queries.

The first query takes about 45 seconds to return 1000 records. The second query takes about 4 seconds to return the same 1000 records. Why? How do I get the first query to run as fast as the second?

Query 1:

```
var groupQuery = Rfqs.Where(rfqs => rfqs.IsPrimaryEmail && (rfqs.Contract != "Upstream"))
    .GroupBy(rfqs => new {rfqs.RFQ_RFISeqNum})
    .Select(g => new {g.Key.RFQ_RFISeqNum, RfqId = g.Max(p => p.RfqId)});
        
var query = (from m in groupQuery
    join t in Rfqs on new {m.RfqId} equals new {t.RfqId}
    join s in RfqSupplementals on new {RfqSeqNumber = t.RFQ_RFISeqNum} equals new {s.RfqSeqNumber}         
    from rfqViewed in RfqVieweds.Where(rv => rv.RfqId == t.RfqId && rv.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from rfqStarred in RfqUserStarreds.Where(rs => rs.RfqSeqNumber == t.RFQ_RFISeqNum && rs.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
    let rcn = RfqCommentNotifications.Where(r => r.RfqSequenceNum == t.RFQ_RFISeqNum && r.SalesRep == salesrep).Select(d => d.LastViewed).FirstOrDefault()
    let ch = RfqsChangeHistories.Where(r => r.RfqRfiSeqNum == t.RFQ_RFISeqNum && chgHistList.Contains(r.Action)).OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
    where (isRfqUser == false || ((t.assignedTo == salesrep || t.secndAssignedTo == salesrep || t.addlAssignedTo == salesrep)
           || (agencies.Contains(t.Agency) && (t.assignedTo == null || t.assignedTo.Trim() == string.Empty)
           && (t.secndAssignedTo == null || t.secndAssignedTo.Trim() == string.Empty) && (t.addlAssignedTo == null || t.addlAssignedTo.Trim() == string.Empty))))
           && (!isRfqUser || t.HouseOpportunity == false)
           && t.IsDeleted == false && t.IsPrimaryEmail
           && (t.ReplyByDate > now || (t.ReplyByDate == null && t.IsManualRfq))
    select new RfqDto()
```

Query 2:

```
var groupQuery = Rfqs.Where(rfqs => rfqs.IsPrimaryEmail && (rfqs.Contract != "Upstream"))
.GroupBy(rfqs => new {rfqs.RFQ_RFISeqNum})
.Select(g => new {g.Key.RFQ_RFISeqNum, RfqId = g.Max(p => p.RfqId)});
    
var query = (from m in groupQuery
join t in Rfqs on new {m.RfqId} equals new {t.RfqId}
join s in RfqSupplementals on new {RfqSeqNumber = t.RFQ_RFISeqNum} equals new {s.RfqSeqNumber}
from rfqViewed in RfqVieweds.Where(rv => rv.RfqId == t.RfqId && rv.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
from rfqStarred in RfqUserStarreds.Where(rs => rs.RfqSeqNumber == t.RFQ_RFISeqNum && rs.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
let rcn = RfqCommentNotifications.Where(r => r.RfqSequenceNum == t.RFQ_RFISeqNum && r.SalesRep == salesrep).Select(d => d.LastViewed).FirstOrDefault()
let ch = RfqsChangeHistories.Where(r => r.RfqRfiSeqNum == t.RFQ_RFISeqNum && chgHistList.Contains(r.Action)).OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
where (isRfqUser == false || ((t.assignedTo == salesrep || t.secndAssignedTo == salesrep || t.addlAssignedTo == salesrep) 
       || (agencies.Contains(t.Agency) && (t.assignedTo == null || t.assignedTo.Trim() == string.Empty) 
       && (t.secndAssignedTo == null || t.secndAssignedTo.Trim() == string.Empty) && (t.addlAssignedTo == null || t.addlAssignedTo.Trim() == string.Empty))))
       && (!isRfqUser || t.HouseOpportunity == false)
       && t.IsDeleted == false && t.IsPrimaryEmail
       && (rfqViewed == null && (t.ReplyByDate > now || (t.ReplyByDate == null && t.IsManualRfq))) 
select new RfqDto()
```

Comment: How many rows of data are being returned in each case?  The time of the query is a function of the size of the database and the amount of data that is transferred.  Both queries will have to search the entire table in the database so I do not think the size of the database is causing the difference in time.  So it seems more likely that first query is returning less data than second.  The data is going into memory so I would watch Task Manager as both queries run and check the amount of memory being used.

Comment: This will not answer the question, but on a such a complex and huge query, consider using a view or stored proc, so that the DB can do some optimizations.

Comment: @jdweng both queries are returning 1000 rows. The only difference between the two queries is the second checks if rfqViewed == null while the first does not.

Comment: Is rfqViewed a key?  You are correct there shouldn't be a huge difference in performance.  Has database been defragmented recently?

Comment: @jdweng No, rfqViewed is the result of "from rfqViewed in RfqVieweds...DefaultIfEmpty()". If reqViewed is null then the user has not viewed that Rfqs record, otherwise they have viewed the Rfqs record.

Comment: It does look like it can take a long time.  You are searching a table RfqVieweds and depending on the size of the table can add significant time.  If you made RfqId (and/or SalesRep) a primary key then the lookup would be made using a hash and reduce time of query.

Comment: @jdweng I made RfqId/SalesRep the primary key for the RfqVieweds table. Query 1 still takes about 45 seconds while query 2 about 3 seconds.

Comment: Did you refresh mapping so database and c# classes both have update?

Comment: So I tried removing parts of the first query and the culprit seems to be the two "let" statements. Without them the first query runs as fast as the second. Any thoughts on why those two statements would cause the slowdown in query 1 but not 2?

Comment: Is this really LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: Check the explain plan. The first query is obviosuly not using indexes and you're getting full table scans. The same goes for the second one. 4 sec for 1000 rows in orders of magnitude too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look at the query plan to see the true reason for the timing difference, as it depends on the actual data.

The two queries are different and if they happen to return the same number of rows, then Sql will have no way of knowing that in advance.

I can give you an example of one circumstance which could cause the difference.

First of all, lets simplify the query to

```
var query = (from m in groupQuery
            join t in Rfqs on new { m.RfqId } equals new { t.RfqId }
            from rfqViewed in RfqVieweds.Where(rv => rv.RfqId == t.RfqId && rv.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where  
                t.ReplyByDate > now 
            select new RfqDto()
```

Now suppose you have 1 million rows in Rfqs and only 1000 records have a ReplyByDate values in the future. If ReplyByDate is not indexed, then that means that sql has to read and check all million rows before returning the selected 1000 rows.

But if the query becomes

```
var query = (from m in groupQuery
            join t in Rfqs on new { m.RfqId } equals new { t.RfqId }
            from rfqViewed in RfqVieweds.Where(rv => rv.RfqId == t.RfqId && rv.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where  
                (t.ReplyByDate > now  
                && rfqViewed == null 
            select new RfqDto()
```

and if it happens that there are only 10000 rows in Rfqs that do not have a record in RfqVieweds, and if rfqViewed has a suitable index that Sql can determine this quickly,  then that means that Sql will only need to look at these 10000 records, which may be faster.

Note, If there are any rows with ReplyDates in the future that have been reviewed, then the two queries will not return the same records.